# The norm of identity minus bilateral shift operator on a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $X=l^2(\mathbb{Z})$ be the Hilbert space of all real sequences $x= (x_{k})_{k}$ $(k\in \mathbb{Z})$ for which the norm $\|x\|= \left( \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} |x_{k}|^{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is finite. denote by ${e_{k}:k\in\mathbb{Z}}$ the canonical basis in  $X$, and define $L: X\longrightarrow X$ by
$$L
\left(\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}x_{k}e_{k}
\right)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}(x_{k}-x_{k-1})e_{k}$$

The question is why $\|L\|=2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $L=I-S_R$ (where $S_R$ is the right shift operator), we have $\|L\|\leq\|I\|+\|S_R\|=2$.
To show the reverse inequality, look at the sequence $x_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}\sum_{k=-n}^n(-1)^ke_k$.  Then $\|x_n\|=1$, with 
$$Lx_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}\left((-1)^ne_{-n}+(-1)^{n+1}e_{n+1}+2\sum_{k=-n}^{n-1}(-1)^ke_k\right).$$
and $\|Lx_n\|=\sqrt{\frac{8n+2}{2n+1}}\to2$ as $n\to\infty$, so $\|L\|\geq2$.