# Does there exist $x \in \ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$ such that $L\big((x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\big) = (x_n-x_{n-1})_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ attains its norm?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $$\ell^2(\mathbb{Z}) = \Bigg\{(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{Z} : \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty |x_n|^2 < +\infty\Bigg\}$$
be equipped with the norm $\|x\|_2 = \sqrt{\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty |x_n|^2}$.

Let $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ be the canonical basis for $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$. Define a bounded linear map $L : \ell^2(\mathbb{Z}) \to \ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$ with 
$$L
\left(\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}x_{k}e_{k}
\right)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}(x_{k}-x_{k-1})e_{k}$$

In other words, $L\big((x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\big) = (x_n-x_{n-1})_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$.

Does there exist $x \in \ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$ such that $\|x\|_2 = 1$ and $\|Lx\|_2 = \|L\|\cdot\|x\|_2$?

---

As shown in an answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2438735/144766), $\|L\| = 2$ so I tried to impose this condition on $x$ somehow:

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty (x_n-x_{n-1})^2 = 4\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty x_k^2 \iff -\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty x_{k-1}x_k = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty x_k^2$$

Equating the series term-by-term, we obtain the sequence $(\ldots, 1, -1, 1, -1, \ldots)$ which is of course not in $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$.

Similarly:

$$-\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty (x_n-x_{n-1})^2 = 4\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty x_k^2 \iff \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty x_{k-1}x_k = 3\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty x_k^2$$

Again, we obtain something like $(\ldots, 27, 9, 3, 1, \frac13, \frac19, \frac1{27} \ldots) \notin \ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$.

I have tried many variations of these, truncating them at some point and similar stuff, but without achieving $\|Lx\|_2 = 2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have shown $\|Lx\|=\|L\|\|x\|$ if and only if $-\sum_nx_{n-1}x_n=\sum_nx_n^2$, so let's go from there. If you apply Cauchy-Schwarz to the left, you find it is $\le$ the right, with equality if and only if there is some constant $\alpha$ such that $x_n=\alpha x_{n-1}$ for all $n$. Split into cases ($\alpha=0$, $0<|\alpha|<1$, $|\alpha|=1$ and $|\alpha|>1$) and verify in each case that this is not possible for an $\ell^2$ sequence.

Comment: You mean $-\sum_nx_{n-1}x_n\ge\sum_nx_n^2$, right? Anyway, I get it, thanks a lot.

Comment: No, I mean $\le$ (technically, since I have included the equivalent conditions for equality, I mean $|\text{LHS}|\le\text{RHS}$). I'm applying Cauchy-Schwarz to $\langle x,y\rangle$ where $y_n=x_{n-1}$.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant.